# Why won't Django load my CSS files when I already used static?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm trying to create a website but idk why some of my CSS is not working on the page. I followed the format my teacher gave and his worked so idk why mine won't.

in urls.py of the project:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('system/', include ('system.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

in HTML file:

```
{% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
```

in CSS file:

```
.body{
    background-color: yellow;
}
.title
{
    color: #000;
    font-family: Arial Black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 4%;
}
.list
{
    color: #000;
    font-family: Arial;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
}
```

When I `python manage.py runserver`, the page background is still white and the text is also white so I have to block them to see it. I tried to do the collectstatic but it gave a warning that it will overwrite existing files so I canceled it. My teacher also haven't taught us the collectstatic command. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `collectstatic` is only for use of production env, check your static settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember having a similar problem, though it's been a while since I worked through it. I believe my eventual solution was adding the code below to my settings file. It also depends on how you set up your file tree since I believe that STATIC_URL is referring to the directory name, though I'd have to double check

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)


STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

Comment: when I used your code it gave an error `name 'os' is not defined` so I tried `STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    '/ssip/hotel/hotel/static/',
]
` and it worked. Thanks for the hint :)

Comment: No problem, glad it worked! And for future reference, os can just be imported. It comes with python (no pip install necessary). (import os)

Answer (score 0):

```
settings.py

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

And then use the command: python manage.py collectstatic

PS: You never told where your CSS file is saved. So perhaps that won't work